# What is the relationship between Teagueduino to Arduino?

Tags: arduino, ide

How are [Teagueduino](http://teagueduino.org/) and Arduino related? Can the Teagueduino IDE be used to program Arduino boards? What is the "upgrade path"? The relevant section in the reference ("[Migrating to Arduino and Beyond](http://teagueduino.org/?p=ref_sw#migrating)") is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The teagueduio seems to be both a hardware and software wrapper to an Arduino Nano or compatible board. Basically it shields you from reality (i.e. the microcontroller and low level programming) even more than the Arduino platform making it even easier to use and less adaptable. You will be able to accomplish fun little projects with little effort or knowledge. This will maximize your fun at the cost of its longevity and deep learning. Whether it is right for you or not depends on your objective. If you know nothing about electronics and programming it is a great place to start. But, if you want to become really proficient at electronics this is just hiding most of the details. I don't support jumping over the fundamentals of a topic just to get to the fun parts. Therefore, I would recommend one of those X-in-1 (where x=100,200,...) electronics type trainers before this personally. A book with a few components and a bread board is great too.

The migrating to Arduino looks as simple as physically unplugging the arduino board from the teaguedunio board and using the arduino IDE instead of the teagueduino's.

Comment: Yes, that's my concern. I like the interactivity of the Teagueduio IDE and its ability to display real time information about the board, but if that only works on Teagueduio boards (and requires a special dialect to boot) it seems like a detour not worth taking.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - the *idea* is certainly portable, if the actual *implementation* is or not depends of if they give you the source code (or at least the hex file) to whatever bootloader they put in their arduino-like board.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Well, if you can learn something that is applicable to a wide range of platforms then I would say that this knowledge is of value. In general seeing the electrical state of pins may be a good learning experience, but, I would prefer to have an oscilloscope and logic analyser for this purpose. You can apply these tools to any platform. Knowing how to use these tools is also a valuable skill in itself.